Problem with currfile and \input
my code is the following:

\documentclass[ngerman,german,14pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{currfile}
%\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\batchmode

\begin{document}

\section*{Hello \currfilebase,}

\input{D:/folder1/test.tex}

\end{document}

The code inside "test.tex" is the following:
\section*{Hello \currfilebase,}


123 123 

My question to the community is the following:
It is said, that using the command "\input" adds the source code from the respective file as if it would have been written right into the source code. But the outcome of my code is the following:

However, I thought that the two lines (see attached picture) should be the same. Why is that the case? I expected the two "results" to be the same, i.e. the second line should also read "currfile test". How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

What do you actually want to do? Maybe \jobname? The definition of current file is the current file so...

@user202729: what I would like to do is the following: I wonder why I don´t get the same result from the "input"-File: I read that "to input" the file should be the same as directly adding the code into the original file. But here I get two results. My intention is to add a report of e.g. a pupil and speak to him oder her with her name. This name would be "test" from "test.tex". Hope that clears the confusion a little bit...

the currfile package explicitly hooks into \input to get the name of the file you input and then changes the currfile macros. If you want the name of the main document, use \jobname, or use the primitive input, which has no hooks: \UseName{@@input}{test}

@Ulrike Fischer: Thank you very much for your suggestion, it works like a charm! One last question please:: how can I get rid of the quotation marks: Hello ”currfile test”,? Thank you very much for your help!

do not use file names with spaces. Or post process the file name to remove the quotes.
