How can I input external files by using a list of names?
My code is the following:

\documentclass[ngerman,german,14pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\batchmode

\begin{document}

\section*{Hello \currfilebase,}

%\InputIfFileExists{file}{then-code}{else-code}
\InputIfFileExists{D:/folder1/Folder2/George.tex}{\UseName{@@input}{D:/folder3/folder4/A_nice_story.tex}}{}\\

\InputIfFileExists{D:/folder1/Folder2/James.tex}{\UseName{@@input}{D:/folder3/folder4/A_nice_story.tex}}{}\\

\InputIfFileExists{D:/folder1/Folder2/Peter.tex}{\UseName{@@input}{D:/folder3/folder4/A_nice_story.tex}}{}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719865/problem-with-currfile-and-input
%see comment of @UlrikeFischer! Thanks a lot!

\end{document} 

I am writing reports for a lot of pupils (at the moment approx. 30 but next semester it will be more then 200) The report is basically the same for all pupils but some of them should get a special chapter (In my example "A nice story"). My question now is if there is a possibility to "shorten" this time consuming process in such a way that I provide the names of the pupils elected for the extra chapter (say George, James, and Peter) in e.g. a list (maybe a *.txt file; external or internal) and that I only need one line of code instead of 100 (each for every pupil). Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Sorry, but this time I totally fail in understanding, what you want (and still why you are using currfile).

You could loop over a list of names (latex has liots of loop macros) or if the file directory structure is regular you could just loop over the files existing in the directory and not need an explcit list in the file) see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714269/1090  (which is using \includegraphics but looping over .tex files and using \input would be the same.

why \UseName{@@input rather than \input ?

@cabohah: Ok, I finally deleted \currfile! My idea is the following:: All pupils will get a "basic" text, but some of them (eg George, James, Peter) should get extra text. I would like to add this extra test by using an e.g. *.txt file in which all the names who should get this extra text will be listed. If the name is an the list then an extra text should be insserted. This task can be done by using the \InputIfFileExists command by it is very tedious for me to do it manually ( see my MWE). I would like to automate this process if possible.

your example is checking if  George.tex exists and if it does input it and then unconditionally input a nice strory.tex (the same one for all case)  that does not match your description, I would hav eexpected you to loop through George,James,peter then unconditionally input ~1.tex and optionally input George-nice-story.tex for George if it exists?

David Carlisle: Regarding your first question: I tried to adapt the solution from the comment of @UlrikeFischer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719865/problem-with-currfile-and-input. Regarding your second comment: I sounds very logical to me but how can I achieve this?

Your example shows that you want to input additional files, if e.g. George.tex has been input successfully. Why don't you just add \input{D:/folder3/folder4/A_nice_story.tex} at the end of George.tex? BTW: I usually would not recommend to use absolute file paths. And absolute Windows file paths are never a good idea in examples. If possible a minimal working example should even avoid relative paths if using paths is not part of the problem.

But if the reality is different than your example, and there are files George.tex, George-Story.tex, Peter.tex, Sarah.tex, Sarah-Story.tex, which means the extra files always have the same name suffix, you could also use \newcommand*{\InputNameAndStory}[1]{\input{#1.tex}\InputIfFileExists{#1-Story.tex}{}{}}. Now, \InputNameAndStory{George} would input George.tex and George-Story.tex, but \InputNameAndStory{Peter} would input only Peter.tex (because a Peter-Story.tex does not exist).

Given a directory structure such as
$ ls -R .
.:
folder  main.tex

./folder:
George.tex  James-Story.tex  James.tex  Peter.tex

containing the files
main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3sys-query}
\def\addstory#1/#2.#3\relax{#1/#2-Story.#3}
\begin{document}


\QueryFiles[exclude=*Story.tex]{folder/*.tex}{%
  \input{#1}\InputIfFileExists{\addstory#1\relax}{}{}}



\end{document}
% or just \QueryFiles{folder/*.tex}{\input{#1}}


George.tex

\section{George}

gggg

James.tex

\section{James}

jjj

James-Story.tex

\subsection{Extra stuff}
stuff about James

Peter.tex

\section{Peter}

ppp

the code loops over all the tex files in the folder skipping over Story ones, then optionally includes the story ones in there.
Actually in this case it would just do that anyway as the Story files come after the name ones so you could omit the test and simply have
\QueryFiles{folder/*.tex}{\input{#1}}

but the filter gives more flexibility for adding extra wording around the additional sections

